# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: public suspend fun delay(timeMillis: Long):

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, splash-screen

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
private val SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 5000


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        delay(SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH)
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        loadWebView()
    }
}

private suspend fun loadWebView() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH)
    }
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}
```

}

This is a Splash Screen. I got this error - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public suspend fun delay(timeMillis: Long): Unit defined in kotlinx.coroutines
public suspend fun delay(duration: Duration): Unit defined in kotlinx.coroutines. Can anybody help me please. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hover over `SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH` and see what type it is. Does it match the argument passed to one of those `delay` functions listed?

Comment: `SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH` is an Int. The `delay()` function expects a Long.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @cactustictacs. I removed SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH and  added the duration directly like this- delay(5000). It worked.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @Tenfour04. I removed SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH and  added the duration directly like this- delay(5000). It worked.

Comment: It would make more sense to keep your constant, but define it as a Long instead of an Int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is another answer thanks to @Tenfour04. [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75352097/none-of-the-following-functions-can-be-called-with-the-arguments-supplied-publi?noredirect=1#comment132997319_75352097)

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class SplashScreen1 : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar

//Define the constant as long instead of int
private val SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 5000L


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_circular)

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        delay(SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH)
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        loadWebView()
    }
}

private suspend fun loadWebView() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH)
    }
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I removed SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH and added the duration directly like this- delay(5000). It worked --

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
class SplashScreen1 : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progrssBar2)

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        delay(3000)
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        loadWebView()
    }
}

private suspend fun loadWebView() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(3000)
    }
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}
}
```